# How to run multiple threads simultaneosly

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, android-camera, framebuffer

I am developing an Android application that opens a video stream using the class JavaCameraView, and captures frames from it. Then, my target is to realize a worker thread that saves these frames into a buffer, and another thread that takes every frame from the buffer, in order to process it with image-processing techniques. 
So the buffer is a resource shared between these two worker threads, that should run simultaneosly, so filling and emptying the buffer at the same time.
I thought to realize the buffer as a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, and the two threads are realized implementing the Runnable interface. Then, in the Main Activity, I declare them, I istantiate them, and then I start them, but it seems that only the first becomes running, and the second never starts.
I post here my code:

1)Buffer.java

```
public class Buffer {
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Mat> MyBuffer = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Mat>();
private static final String TAG = "MyBufferClass :: ";
private int index = 1;

public Buffer(){
    Log.d(TAG,"Buffer Created");
}

public void insertElementInTail(Mat element){
    MyBuffer.offer(element);
}

public Mat retrieveElementInHead(){
    synchronized (MyBuffer){
        if(!MyBuffer.isEmpty()){
            return MyBuffer.peek();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public Mat removeElementInHead(){
    synchronized (MyBuffer){
        if(!MyBuffer.isEmpty()){
            return MyBuffer.poll();
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public int getSize(){
    return MyBuffer.size();
}
}
```

2)SaveInBuffer.java

```
public class SaveInBuffer implements Runnable {

private Handler myHandler;
private Buffer myBuffer;

public Handler myThreadHandler;
MainActivity mainActivity;
Handler mainHandler;
int what = -1;


public SaveInBuffer(Buffer myBuf, MainActivity mainActivity){
    //super("SaveInBuffer");
    this.myBuffer = myBuf;
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    this.mainHandler = mainActivity.mainHandler;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();
    myThreadHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage( Message msg ){
             if(msg.what==4){
                 Mat returnedFrame = (Mat)msg.obj;
                 myBuffer.insertElementInTail(returnedFrame);
             }
        }
    };
    Looper.loop();
}

}
```

3)TakeFromBuffer.java

```
public class TakeFromBuffer implements Runnable{

public Handler consumerHandler;
private Buffer myBuffer;

public TakeFromBuffer(Buffer myBuffer){
    this.myBuffer = myBuffer;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();
    Mat consumedFrame = myBuffer.removeElementInHead();
    Looper.loop();
}
}
```

The buffer is created within the MainActivity, and then passed as parameter to the threads. The question is how to manage the Buffer as a shared resource, so implementing synchronization techniques, and how to start the two threads simultaneosly, because it's really important that they run at the same time.

How could I do?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html. use a executor

Comment: Try to use thread pool executor.. And you can start the thread i.e. ur parallel execution. You can even use AsyncTask for your implementation  as It allows parallel execution after API 11. See if this helps.

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment. Only a question: so using Executor I can run my Runnables at the same time, simply calling the method execute for both of them?

Comment: Thanks to all. I try immediately these solutions.

Comment: ya u can pass ur runnable in excute. Plese let us know if it worked

Comment: I have finally solved using this class: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. In this way, I start the first thread and after a few seconds, needed to fill the buffer, I start also the second thread and it works!! Thanks to all, your suggestions helped me to understand the way!